# Hover image enlarge using css, in front of other images

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have a table with images and have set up some css to enlarge the images and display text on hover. I'm having trouble with the images enlarging in back of the other images. I need the hover enlarged image to be in front of the rest.

Here's the Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/eF5CX/

HTML:

```
<table width="522" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
      <tr>
        <td width="179"><div class="imageWrapper1"><a href="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/events_cocktails.php"><img src="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/images/cocktails.jpg" name="cocktails" width="179" height="265" border="0" align="top" id="cocktails" /></a><a href="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/events_cocktails.php" class="cornerLink">August 22 Friday Night Cocktails at Oakbrook CC</a></div></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"><div class="imageWrapper1"><a href="events_gala.php"><img src="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/images/gala.jpg" name="gala" width="331" height="397" border="0" align="top" id="gala" /></a><a href="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/events_gala.php" class="cornerLink">8/23 Saturday Night Gala</a></div></td>
        <td width="1">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="129"><div class="imageWrapper1"><a href="events_golf.php"><img src="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/images/golf.jpg" name="golf" width="179" height="129" border="0" align="top" id="golf" /></a><a href="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/events_golf.php" class="cornerLink">8/23 Golf Tournament</a></div></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="518" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
      <tr>
        <td width="293"><div class="imageWrapper1"><a href="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/events_picnic.php"><img src="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/images/picnic.jpg" name="picnic" width="286" height="214" border="0" align="top" id="picnic" /></a><a href="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/events_picnic.php" class="cornerLink">8/24 Beach Picnic</a></div></td>
        <td width="222"><div class="imageWrapper1"><a href="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/events_car.php"><img src="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/images/car.jpg" alt="" name="car" width="220" height="214" border="0" align="top" id="car" /></a><a href="http://cloverparklakes6450.com/events_car.php" class="cornerLink">8/24 Collector Car Cruise</a></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
    .imageWrapper1:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    height:auto;
    width: auto;
    transform:scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(1.1); /* Opera */
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #111111;
}
.imageWrapper1 {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.imageWrapper1 img {
    display: block;
}
.imageWrapper1 .cornerLink {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;

}
.imageWrapper1:hover .cornerLink {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Please make a http://www.jsfiddle.net with your relevant code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eF5CX/

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/eF5CX/1/ I just added z-index to the hover wrapper

Answer (score 5):

Just give an z-index to hover.
It will work.
Just like below;

```
.imageWrapper1:hover .cornerLink {
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Great. Would point out that the z-index value is largely arbitrary if nothing else on the page has a z-index and relative position set (so, in my case, even setting the z-index to 1 was enough, since users can only zoom one image at a time in our docs)

Answer (score 0):

I would put a wrapper around the Image and scale this wrapper.

Like so:

```
<table class="content">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="zoom-img">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JABvKgL.jpg" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="zoom-img">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JABvKgL.jpg" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyVLQ/) for you.

Comment: I need the entire image to enlarge though. I'm going for this look http://www.rareview.com/ .. and I like the text effect too http://www.zaptravel.com/from-phoenix/quality